# Can't convert VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to convert `VB.NET` application to `C#`. Project has the following lines:

```
inTrip.Stops.AddRange(trip.Stops)
inTrip.Stops.ForEach(Sub(s) s.Trip = inTrip)
```

but I don't understand clearly what it does so I can't convert it. What is correct code of `C#` for these lines?

**EDIT**

As I understand, it should be like:

```
foreach (var item in trip.Stops)
{
    var item_db = mapper.Map<TripStop>(item);
    inTrip.TripStops.Add(item_db);
}

foreach (var item in inTrip.TripStops)
{
    item.Trip = inTrip;
}
```

but these cycle references (inTrip has collection of TripStops and for each element of collection set Trip element again) confuses me

Comment: I'm not a VB.NET programmer. Yet I can read that pretty easily. The first line adds one collection to another. The second line loops over a collection with a lambda expression and assigns a value to a property of the items in the collection. The C# is almost the exact same. I think you can figure this out.

Comment: Pretty simple. Just add a semicolon to the end of both lines, then change `Sub(s)` to `s => `

Comment: it saw it's a pretty simple to. But I get an error(s): 'ICollection<TripStop>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<TripStop>' and 'ICollection<TripStop>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<TripStop>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you actually tried *something* on your own?

Comment: @AlexB., I moved the whole project from VB.NET to C#, but these strings are confused me...

Comment: I have created topic by mistake

Comment: Your edit doesn't really make sense. What confuses you? Do you have an additional question?

Answer (score 1):

The code:

1. Appends the `trip.Stops` collection to `inTrip.Stops`
2. Runs a `foreach` loop over `inTrip.Stops` with a lambda expression, setting a "parent" property to `inTrip`

The C# code is very similar; just different syntax for the lambda expression:

```
inTrip.Stops.AddRange(trip.Stops);
inTrip.Stops.ForEach((s) => s.Trip = inTrip);
```

Comment: I get an error(s): 'ICollection<TripStop>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<TripStop>' and 'ICollection<TripStop>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<TripStop>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @maccettura, yes

Comment: @OlegSh Those methods are usually used with `List` not `ICollection`. Can you change the property type to `List`?

Comment: @maccettura, added too